# SQL Query taking a long time

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to run this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
      t.class_name,
      t.class_code,
      @UTCTimeNow,
      @Username 
FROM 
      tblimport_n t
      LEFT JOIN classmaster_n cm ON t.class_code = cm.classcode
WHERE 
      cm.classcode IS NULL
```

But this is taking so long(between 7-8 mins). This is the current state

tblImport contains 27k records

tblImport has fulltext index on class_code

classmaster_n contains 27k records

classmaster_n has index on classcode

Is it taking considerable time? I doubt!

In future both the tables can have 0.1 million records! I am afraid of that result!

**EDIT :**

What I am trying to get is, all the records from `tblImport`, those are not in `classmaster_n`.

Actually I want to insert all the classes that does not already exists in the database. I will be using this query to insert records.

**EDIT 2**

Changed `FULLTEXT` index type in `tblImport`_n table to normal index

Explain for my query shows this

```
id  select_type  table   type    possible_keys  key                      key_len  ref       rows  Extra                                 

 1  SIMPLE       t       ALL     (NULL)         (NULL)                   (NULL)   (NULL)   27071                                        
 1  SIMPLE       cm      index   (NULL)         i_Classmaster_Classcode  202      (NULL)   27251  Using where; Using index; Not exists
```

tblImport_n

```
CREATE TABLE `tblimport_n` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `SCHOOL_CODE` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SCHOOL_NAME` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CLASS_CODE` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CLASS_NAME` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TEACHER_EMPLOYEE_CODE` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TEACHER_TITLE` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TEACHER_FIRSTNAME` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TEACHER_MIDDLENAME` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TEACHER_LASTNAME` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TEACHER_EMAIL_ADDRESS` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `STAFF_CODE` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `STUDENT_CODE` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `STUDENT_FIRSTNAME` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `STUDENT_MIDDLENAME` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `STUDENT_LASTNAME` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `STUDENT_GRADE` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `STUDENT_GENDER` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `STUDENT_BIRTH_DATE` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `STUDENT_HOMEROOM` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `STUDENT_IEP_STATUS` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `STUDENT_LEP_STATUS` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `STUDENT_LEP_Year` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `STUDENT_RACE` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `STUDENT_LANGUAGE` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `STUDENT_NETWORK` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `STUDENT_ACCOMMODATIONS` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DISTRICTID` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TMD5hash` varchar(1500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SMD5hash` varchar(1500) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `i1` (`CLASS_CODE`),
  KEY `i2` (`SCHOOL_CODE`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=32768 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

classmaster_n

```
CREATE TABLE `classmaster_n` (
  `ClassId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ClassName` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `ClassCode` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `CreatedDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `CreatedUser` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `UpdatedDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `UpdatedUser` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ClassId`),
  KEY `i_Classmaster_Classcode` (`ClassCode`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=35094 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

**EDIT 3**

I think I made it!!!

I just changed `tblImport_n.Class_Code` to non null column and the query took just 27secs!!

I am still testing all the cases...

Comment: what is `@UTCTimeNow` and `@Username`?

Comment: You're joining using cm.classcode, but requiring cm.classcode to be null? Am guessing that's a table scan. Can you say more about what you're trying to do>

Comment: Are you sure you need a FULLTEXT index on a 'code'. That seems odd.

Comment: @echo_Me - Actually this statement is inside stored procedure and `@UTCTimeNow` and `@Username` are the variables. I will be using this result set to insert into one of the tables.

Comment: @asantaballa - Actually I want to get all the records those are in `tblImport` but not in `classmaster_n`. Actually trying to achieve `MINUS`. There are other ways too, like using `NOT IN` or `NOT EXISTS` but all are taking almost same time

Comment: Agree with @Strawberry.  You want B-Tree, not `FULLTEXT` indexes here.

Comment: If you're still struggling, provide proper DDLs for the above, together with an EXPLAIN.

Comment: which column you want it be to be distinct?

Comment: @echo_Me - `class_code` and `class_name`

Comment: Try INSERT IGNORE(http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html)

Comment: @Strawberry - Posted the explain and the DDLs

Answer (score 1):

Try with NOT EXISTS clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
      t.class_name,
      t.class_code,
      @UTCTimeNow,
      @Username 
FROM tblimport_n t
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT 'X' FROM classmaster_n cm WHERE t.class_code = cm.classcode)
```

Because your LEFT JOIN with WHERE condition on classcode is null is the same thing

Comment: I already tried this but it was taking the same time. I mentioned in one of my comments

Comment: Sorry, we have posted at the same time our comments. Have you tried with index on classcode? The DISTINCT is useful? I copy DISTINCT by your query but peraphs is unuseful

Comment: There is index on classcode. And actually yes I need distinct records

Comment: We try another approach: I hope is more speed. Pass 1: Create a temp table where you put select distinct class_name class_code in this way: SELECT DISTINCT class_name, class_code from tbimport_n. Pass 2: After you condition your new table with not existing classmaster

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    SELECT 
  t.class_name,
  t.class_code,
  @UTCTimeNow,
  @Username 
FROM 
  tblimport_n t
  LEFT JOIN classmaster_n cm ON t.class_code = cm.classcode
WHERE 
  cm.classcode IS NULL
group by  t.class_name, t.class_code
```

Comment: Taking the same time :(